# TabbarController in UIViewController in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, tabbarcontroller

I'm pretty much new to iphone development and I started with ViewBasedApplication and I have a  UIViewController(GetDetails) and I'm adding a tabBarController to it .There are two tabbar items GetDetails and Login.On startup of app   GetDetails view will load up.Now when I click on the other tabbaritem (Login )it has to redirect to LoginViewController.But in my app when I click on Login ,LoginViewController with two textboxes and a button is loaded.But the problem is additionally I am also getting the textbox and button of GetDetailsViewController.For Login tabbaritem I have set the nib name to LoginViewController..

How can I get the corresponding view only when a tabbar item is clicked ?

[image: GetDetailsViewController]
[image: When I click on secondtabbaritem I can see like this..with GetDetails also displayed in the background]
[image: TabbarController]
[image]

Comment: How have you added your tab bar items? Programatically or with interface builder? A screenshot of your tab bar controller in interface builder would help.

Comment: I did it with interfacebuilder.Those were the tabbaritems that come as default when I add a Tabbarcontroller..... I have edited my screenshots...Can u please tell me where Im going wrong?